# Does the bootcamp with Windows 10 use the same kernel that the MacOS uses on a Macbook Pro?

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows, kernel

I am just wondering how the boot camp on the macbook pro works? Does it use the same exact kernel as the one that the MacOS uses? Or does bootcamp switch over to a kernel for the windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

Windows works on a Mac that same as a PC. The words "Boot Camp" are associated with the following.

- There is a Boot Camp Assistant application included with macOS that can download the Windows Support Software and aid in the installation and removal of Windows.
- There is the "Boot Camp Support Software" (which has been renamed "Windows Support Software") which contains the Windows drivers and other software to be installed in Windows.
- The name of the volume where Windows is installed is labeled "BOOTCAMP".
- There is a Boot Camp application which is accessible from the Windows Control Panel and System Tray.

When you boot to Windows on a Mac, you are running an entirely difference operating system from macOS. If fact, once Windows is installed on your Mac, you could remove macOS entirely.